# What's the principle inside this js tree?

Tags: javascript

http://jsbin.com/idala

How is it implemented?

Comment: Can you ask a more generic question? It is implemented in Javascript!

Comment: This isn't really a question.  You can see the source code of an page on jsbin by appending `/edit` to the url: http://jsbin.com/idala/edit

Answer (score 2):

The creator used [javascript prototype feature](http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-prototype-property-in-javascript) (not the popular [Prototype framework](http://www.prototypejs.org/)) to create a Christmas Tree class named chrisTree.

There are methods implemented to perform the 'drawing' of the tree as well as the animation by:

- Dynamically creating DOM elements to represent the trees
- Manipulation of CSS styles
- Using `setTimeout` method for animation effect triggering
- etc. etc.

Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript making use of x, y coordinates, arrays and bit of css. You got to analyze it closely to get an idea of how it works. Of course you should have good understanding of javascript. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating div elements which are absolutely positioned so that it appears as a tree.
2. Settimeout used to light up divs
3. Colors are stored in an array

You can view the code using the following link and understand what is being done

http://jsbin.com/idala/edit